# getting the ie edition without calling jquery

Tags: javascript, html

hi first (Jezen Thomas ty your code help me, but i cant use it),  i have to make this code work with out calling  jquery (since we dont know if it will be supported), so basically i have to get this code to show the ie version, only using html and javascript

```
<html> 
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]--
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->              
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>A HTML document needs a title to be valid.</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function mytest(){
"use strict";
// Detecting IE
var oldIE
if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8')) {
oldIE = 1;
    }

if (oldIE == 1) {
   document.write("version<ie9")
    } else {
   document.write(" version => ie9")
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have to remove the ($) but i dont know for what to replace it (i just recently started with javascript)

Comment: why wouldn't jquery be supported?

Comment: we dont even think it support javascript

Comment: Are you trying to do this without JavaScript, or just without using the jQuery library? What is it you're trying to achieve, what's your intended end-result?

Comment: And what have _you_ tried to solve it? Remember, we're here to help, not to do your all work for you.

Comment: if it doesn't support javascript at all, there is no way you can do this. edit: you can do this by reading the user agent, in PHP/ASP.

Comment: Just a heads up. jQuery is a library built in JavaScript. Technically what you have is `only html and javascript`. jQuery is not special. It's just a JavaScript library with predefined functions.

Comment: ok, so the error is on my part,  ty war10ck, also guys sorry if it looked like i wanted you guys to do it for me, i was only asking for directions, i never touch js and from nowhere they toss this to me, and said good luck, so im kind of completly lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alert(navigator.userAgent);

I hope that give you the start you need.

Comment: Unfortunately the userAgent property can be spoofed so this is not a reliable method of determining the browser.

Comment: something is something at least

Comment: anything can be spoofed ... any system or method can be fooled

Comment: @cliffbarnes agreed so what's the point in trying to determine the system being used in the first place? Feature detection is the way to go.

Comment: Wish i could upvote @War10ck so many times on that one. "Feature detection is the way to go."

Comment: Ask him....he obviously wanted a simple solution...i just gave him what he wanted...i can't disagree with what you guys are saying...but maybe his client just wants some quick easy and cheap...???

Comment: actually cliff you gave me the answer with that tip i manage to find what ie we were using and why we where getting the javascrip error, that was all i needed a starting point, ty

Comment: I am glad, Damian. Many times here and elsewhere in the 'real world' or programming it is not about your technical brilliance, but you ability to communicate effectively. Most here have the former, much less have the latter.

Comment: yeah thats true, thank god that they are people that know how to interpret thing, again thank you,war10ck, and lifeinthegray for the help you guys really help me out